# Floated Tableless Layout

Tags: css, css-float

Can anyone tell me how to execute this layout with floats and clears? Ive been trying for 2 days with total failure

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why it *must* be tableless?

Comment: Only CSS ? You can use JS: http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

Comment: @Dmitri: because using tables for layout-issues is heavily frowned upon, and will almost certainly cause problems later.

Comment: @joksnet: Why would you use JS to fix a simple layout, if it's all possible with CSS? performance-wise CSS is a much better choice.

Comment: @Jasper: For two columns CSS works well, but I you need more flexibility (like arrange elements vertically then horizontally) this plugin works well.

Comment: @Jasper, I think you are suffering from "divitus", a new syndrome when designers trying to use divs for everything. The truth is that tables are not a bad way to do the layout on a web page. Most browsers understand tables more uniformly than divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be pretty simple, it's a basic 2 column layout with a header.

Something like this should work fine:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="header">1</div>
 <div id="column1">
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
 </div>
 <div id="column2">
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And some basic CSS

```
#column1, #column2{
width:45%;
float:left;
}
```

I've put a quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9DfRg/

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I used. Relatively quick n easy

Comment: Glad to have helped. Feel free to set this as the accepted answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

of course there are many solutions. One could be the following:

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one">One</div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
  <div id="three">Three</div>
  <div id="four">Four</div>
  <div id="five">Five</div>
  <div id="six">Six</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper {
    width:960px;
}
#one {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:#0C9;
}
#two, #three, #four, #five, #six {
    width:480px;
}
#two, #four, #six {
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}
#three, #five {
    float:right;
}
#three {
    height:200px;
}
#five {
    height:150px;
}
#two {
    background:#06F;
}
#three {
    background:#093;
}
#four {
    background:#699;
}
#five {
    background:#F06;
}
#six {
    background:#666;
}
```

live example: http://jsbin.com/iquyu5